# Figuring out Subnet ID and Host ID from an IP address

Tags: networking, ip, subnet

I have an exam practice question which reads: `a class B network node has an IP address 10.10.155.59 and subnet mask 255.255.248.0. What's the subnet ID and host ID in decimal?`
I know the answer is 38 and 827 so it's not homework help - would just love a simple explanation of how it got there. Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Get your money back for that. Network classes are dead, killed in 1993, by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). Modern networking doesn't use classes. Please let them rest in peace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you mean? Yet I think your **38** is incorrect.

```
10.10.155.59 = 00001010.00001010.10011011.00111011
```

So a class B network is /16 and you have a /21 network. So you would get this:

```
00001010.00001010 - 10.10 = Network ID (16 bits)
10011 - 19 = Subnet ID (5 bits)
01100111011 - 827 = Host ID (11 bits)
```

Also have a look [here](http://www.thenetworkadministrator.com/hack/SubnetAddressing.htm).

Comment: I know this's an old question ,but I'm new to this and I have a little confused here: as I studied, `class B` address start with 2 bit `10` in there first octet (something like 10xx xxxx.X.Y.Z), so why `10.10.155.59` is an class B address ? (10 = 00001010 in binary)

Answer (score 0):

You have to check that in which octet the change is going to occur, so in your question it is 3rd octet so take the 3rd octet (155) & change it to binary then and (multiply) it with the subnet mask /21 in which two octets are already completed (/16) just the 3rd octet is there in which the change is occurred means some bits of 3rd octet are on & some are off.

3rd octet binary is 11111000 & and (multiply) it with the 155 binary 10011011 whatever the answer will be that will be considered the network ID of the given IP